# How would I pull in the first Matrix block including certain blocks only

Tags: matrix

I have a Matrix field setup. I want to be able to pull in the first Matrix block used to print a snippet, but only out of the blocks 'text' or 'textImage'. So the first one used, out of those two only.[image]

This is what I have but it's pulling in the textContent block regardless, even if the text block is first.

```
    {% set textBlock = entry.body.type('text').first() %}
    {% set textBlock2 = entry.body.type('textImage').first() %}


    {% if textBlock %}
        <p>{{ textBlock.textContent|hacksaw(chars='100', append='...') }}</p>

        {% else %}

        {% if textBlock2 %}

        <p>{{ textBlock2.text|hacksaw(chars='100', append='...') }}</p>
        {% endif %}

    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this ago.

It will grab the first block that is either "Text" or "Text Image" and then you can use a switch statement to output your template depending on the block type.

```
{% set firstTextBlock = entry.body.type(['text', 'textImage']).first() %}

{% switch firstTextBlock.type %}

    {% case 'text' %}
        <p>{{ firstTextBlock.textContent|hacksaw(chars='100', append='...') }}</p>

    {% case 'textImage' %}
        <p>{{ firstTextBlock.text|hacksaw(chars='100', append='...') }}</p>

{% endswitch %}
```

Comment: Doesn't like {% switch firstTextBlock.type %} error: Impossible to access an attribute ("type") on a null variable

Comment: It sounds like you might not have any block matching the "text" or "textImage" type in your matrix. That said, I should have wrapped the switch in an if statement to allow for that.

`{% if firstTextBlock %} _switch_ {% endif %}`